# Use screen to execute command from commandline

Tags: linux, command-line, gnu-screen

Is there a way wherein we can start a screen, execute a command and detach it without actually entering into the screen? something like

```
screen -[some option] [command tobe executed]
```

I need this because i have about 100 files that each have different input files and i need to run each on a screen and if the above is possible all i need to do is create a shell script..

Is there an option in screen that would let me do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run screen in detached mode by using the `-d -m` option, eg.

```
screen -d -m some_cmd
```

Comment: thanks.. but what if i want to redirect the output to a file? like
screen -d -m sudo ./mycode &>output
but this just gives a blank file and the output is actually displayed inside the screen..

Answer (score 1):

Try `tmux` (http://tmux.sourceforge.net/). It is much more suited to be used in this manner. Screen is optimized for interactive usage.